# Drupal 7 - Images are not displaying on Front Page

Tags: image, drupal-7, frontpage

I've looked far and wide and am unable to resolve why my article images are not appearing on the Front Page. (Even disabled my CSS to see if that was interfering with it, but no.)

I have created a simple test Article and uploaded an image, yet when it's promoted to the front page, the image does not display.

Only the title, and body displays. When I click on the article, it displays the image, is there a setting I'm missing for this to display?

Comment: This should  probably be migrated to drupal.stackexchange, also you'd need to provide the code for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what is happening is that when you create a node, by default only a "teaser" gets posted to the front page, which may not include an image or the full body. Edit the content type - example.net/admin/structure/types/manage/page/display to change what is displayed in your "teaser".

Comment: I've checked it and it's set to display an image. You led me in the right direction, I changed teaser to full content in custom display and saved and it showed the image. I then set it back to teaser in the same menu and it shows an image. Some odd bug I'm guessing.